# Phonegap Build error: PhoneGap 3.5.0 not supported

Tags: cordova

I make a test mobile application.I try to upload the zip file on build.phonegap.com but I receive this error:PhoneGap 3.5.0 not supported .

I'm newbie on this but I understand that the apps will be build on build.phonegap.com ,your zip have to contain just the assets file(the website) and the build.phonegap will compile to work for all platforms ,am I right?

On the zip file I remove the cordova.js file from the js folder and I removed from index.html ,too ?

DO you know any solution for this error?

Comment: Problem solved...I remove my config.xml file

Answer (score 4):

Phonegap Build does not support 3.5.0 yet afaik. The highest you can go is 3.4.0. But should be fine, no? Just change the number in your config.xml

3.5.0 is only for Phonegap at the moment. That is the Phonegap installed on your machine with the Android SDK or Xcode.

For Phonegap Build you do not need (and should not add) cordova.js or phonegap.js

BUT you do need the reference to phonegap.js in the header of your index.html

Edit: I understand (from PGB) that 3.5.0 is coming to PhoneGap Build this month or next month.